# How to Topple a Cube over via Script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just want to topple a cube over front side of it. But I can't figure out how can I do this. I'm making a game with dice. It won't be rolled, just rotate 90 degrees and move forward 1 unit. How can I do it? Is there an easy way with rigidbody or should I do it all manually changing position and rotation.

By the way, sorry for bad English.

Comment: How do you want it to look? If you want it to interact with nearby objects and be imprecise (a "realistic" turn) then use a rigidbody. If you want it to rotate exactly 90 degrees and move forward one unit, then don't use a rigidbody. Generally, the rigidbody solution will be much harder than changing it directly.

Comment: It must be exactly 90 degrees and one unit. But I want it to be also a realistic turn. So I must do it realistic myself I think.

Comment: What do you mean by realistic? If it's exactly 90 degrees and exactly one unit, it doesn't seem like something that would happen in real life. Do you just mean gradual? (Interpolated?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get an empty `GameObject`, lets call it `flipper', and send it to the bottom edge of the cube you want to be pivoted on.
2. Parent the flipper to the cube.
3. Rotate `flipper` by 90 degrees.
4. Unparent the flipper.
5. Repeat.